# get select dropdown text to textbox using drag and drop jquery

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

We recently migrated from sqlserver to mysql and because of being case sensitive user type the wrong tablename and it fails on UI. So I am trying to facilitate mysql query UI page to copy exact name of the table from dropdown using drag and drop -

Tried Like below code-

```
    $("#droppable").droppable({
    hoverClass: 'active',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        this.value += $(ui.draggable).text();
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5DCZw/1024/

Trying to select one option and drag it to textarea next to "select * from " to make it query.

But issue is that its copying the whole data of dropdown not the one which I have selected.please suggest what I am missing here.

Comment: Pete, sorry did not get you. how come its a problem ? want to know for future posts.

Comment: got it now! thanks Pete for help me understanding the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to do something like this in your drop method

```
drop: function (event, ui) {
  this.value += $(ui.draggable).find('select option:selected').text();
}
```

You are dragging the parent div, so in your drop method you would have to traverse from the dragged div till select element.

Here is a [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/5DCZw/1026/)

Comment: got it! Thanks a lot for explaining the mistake and quick reply, Dhiraj. Worked for me.